# How do I determine kashrut status of fresh produce from Israel?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, eretz-yisrael, agriculture, fruits, state-of-israel

Fresh produce from Israel has all sorts of halachic concerns: Orla, Shemittah, Terumot and Maasrot.

Periodically, I come across fresh fruit imported from Israel.  I generally avoid buying it, but I'd rather know where to find answers to all the questions than just avoid them.

The most recent issue: This time of year (March - April), Costco (in the US) carries Orri mandarins.  Orri mandarins are grown locally here in Florida, but the ones at Costco are labelled "Product of Israel" and have no kashrut certification on the packaging.

Given that it's early April, just after a Shemittah year, the biggest question about these mandarins is whether they are from last year (the Shemittah year) or this year.  Where can I find information about growing seasons?

I also wonder whether it's possible that they are Orla.

I have heard people claim that all produce exported from Israel is certified to have some minimal level of kashrut by the Rabbanut HaRashit.  If this is true, what are the details?

To be clear, I am **not** asking for answers to halachic questions, i.e. what do to with Shemittah fruit.  The information I need is about growing seasons, tree lifecycles, and about what role the Rabbanut plays is overseeing exported fresh produce that isn't explicitly certified kosher.

Ideally, the answer I'm looking for would list some resources that discuss the following topics:

1. growing seasons in Israel for any given fruit or vegetable
2. how long it takes any given type of tree to produce fruit that meet the typical quality standards for export.
3. To what extent, if any, the Rabbanut oversees all produce exported from Israel.

**UPDATE**
This article has thorough coverage of my exact question about Shemittah status:
http://theshc.org/israeli-fruit-for-the-american-consumer/

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/separating-terumah-and-maaser/

Comment: Isaac, from that link "Many people mistakenly believe that the Chief Rabbinate of Israel separates terumah and ma’aser from all produce exported to America. Our office clarified this matter with the Rabbanut and, regrettably, this is presently not the case." In the footnotes it also discusses specific fruits as relates to Orlah

Comment: Thank you for clarifying.  That definitely settles parts 2 and 3 of my question.

Comment: Interesting question. Hard enough for me to follow on these issues in Israel. But just to clarify. Israeli mandarins which would show up in the US now would have grown last year and would be subject to the laws of shmitta. Most likely they are *heter mechira* which you might or might not accept (the Israeli rabbanut does organize it, mehadrin kashrut doesn't use *heter mechira*).

Comment: @mbloch Can you link to a source for the Rabbanut's mechira?  Does that apply to the entire country or famers have to opt in?

Comment: @IsaacBetesh not sure what you mean by "a source for the Rabbanut mechira". But no it doesn't apply to the entire country, rather specific farmers opt in. Others open to let the land unworked. Others opt to work with "Otzar Beit Din". See [here](http://www.eretzhemdah.org/Data/UploadedFiles/SitePages/180-sFileRedirEn.pdf) for some background and [here](http://www.koltorah.org/ravj/hetermechira1.htm)

Comment: What I mean is that you said "most likely they are heter mechira" and I was wondering what your source is for saying that is "most likely".  Even if it is true about most produce, that doesn't necessarily mean it's the most likely status of produce that is under no certification, so I am looking for more details about who opts into the mechira.

Comment: @mbloch your first link does say "In the present Shmitta year, the vast majority of land used for growing vegetables and some of the land used for growing fruits was sold to non-Jews."  However, it's not clear what year this was written, and it's not clear what portion of the remaining fruit farmers opted into Otzar Beit Din and what portion simply don't follow the laws of Shemittah.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh either last year or 8 years ago - based on the references to the books they published (bottom of page). If important to you I can ask one of the rabbanim there. But from leaving in Israel I can saw the majority of produce sold in still *heter mechira* so same situation as what is described

Comment: @IsaacBetesh but just to be clear, DO NOT rely on what I wrote here to apply shmitta laws to produce you might buy in the US. In a nutshell, if the produce is heter mechira it doesn't need extra treatment. But if it is otzar beit din (although I doubt it very much) it has *kdushat shviit* and needs to be handled extra carefully (e.g., do not throw away remains in the trash)

Comment: @IsaacBetesh last none of this has to do with the kashrut of the fruit but with shmitta and how to handle fruit with *kdushat shviit*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37972/discussion-between-isaac-betesh-and-mbloch).

Answer (score 2):

This lists the Last Dates of Kedushas Shevi’is, Sefichin and Biur 5775/5776:

http://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/3023/last-dates-of-kedushas-sheviis-sefichin-and-biur-57755776/

Here is a Stark-K article on how to act post Shemitta:

http://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/3020/charting-the-course-of-shmitta-5776-a-consumers-guide-to-post-shmitta/

Comment: Josh welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.